# Purchases I did not download do not appear in iTunes library

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes, ipad

In both my MacBook and my iPad, all my purchases that I did not download do not appear in my library.

They are in the Purchased section but do not appear in the library for me to stream from the cloud. This isn't an issue on my iPhone for some reason. When I go to "View" on the top bar my MacBook, there is no option for selecting whether or not I want to display downloaded content only.

How do I get my iPhone settings to sync to my iPad and Mac or do I need to perform some steps on them?

Comment: In iTunes settings, do you have iCloud Music Library on?

Comment: I do not, but this problem is also for movies and TV shows, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The first item is to check on the iPhone to be sure you are using the iCloud Music Library / iTunes Match / Apple Music settings there as you expect.

Then you’ll repeat the inspection on all other devices to have them match up with your iPhone if that has the library / playlists / features and media you want to go to all the devices.